# Swift 5 conversion confused about usage of?

Tags: swift, swift5

I store an array of CLLocation in UserDefaults using the code below to unarchive it.

When converting the project to Swift 5 it changed the code a bit adding "as [CLLocation]??" at the end and I am confused about what the double ?? means here.
If it would have said [CLLocation]? then I would have understood it meaning that the operation will return a [CLLocation] array or nil.

I am however not sure how to interpret the [CLLocation]??. I am aware how the coalescing works normally but in this scenario I do not know.

This was the pre-swift 5 code:

```
if let coordinatesArray = try? NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedArrayOfObjects(ofClass: CLLocation.self, from: coordinatesArrayData) {
  return coordinatesArray
}
```

And this is after the update.

```
if let coordinatesArray = ((try? NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedArrayOfObjects(ofClass: CLLocation.self, from: coordinatesArrayData)) as [CLLocation]??) {
  return coordinatesArray
}
```

Can anyone explain how to interpret the [CLLocation]??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behaviour of `try?` has changed in Swift 5, as described in [SE-0230](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0230-flatten-optional-try.md). If the expression after "`try?`" is an optional type, no additional layers of optional will be added. Since you are converting your old code, Xcode tries not to break it, maintaining the old behaviour by wrapping it back to a double optional.

The old behaviour is as follows:

1. `unarchivedArrayOfObjects` returns a `Optional<[CLLocation]>`
2. `try?` takes the type of the expression next to it, `Optional<[CLLocation]>` and wraps it in another `Optional`, so you get `Optional<Optional<[CLLocation]>>`, aka `[CLLocation]??`.
3. Then the `if let` unwraps one level of `Optional`, and `coordinatesArray` ends up being of type `Optional<[CLLocation]>`

If Xcode does nothing when converting to Swift 5, this will happen:

1. `unarchivedArrayOfObjects` returns a `Optional<[CLLocation]>`
2. the entire `try?` expression is still of type `Optional<[CLLocation]>`.
3. Then the `if let` unwraps one level of `Optional`, and `coordinatesArray` ends up being of type `[CLLocation]`.

As you can see, your code is now returning a totally different type. Xcode wraps it in another layer of optionals, to at least keep the types the same.

```
(
    (
        try? NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedArrayOfObjects(ofClass: CLLocation.self, from: coordinatesArrayData)
    )
    as [CLLocation]??
)
```

This will still not have the same behaviour as your old code though. I think putting the cast inside the `try?` expression should produce the same behaviour:

```
try? (
    NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedArrayOfObjects(ofClass: CLLocation.self, from: coordinatesArrayData) 
    as [CLLocation]??
)
```

Comment: Thank you @Sweeper for the detailed explanation. Especially about the 2 layers of optionals. The solution suggested below removed this extra layer of complexity.

Comment: @user1816142 so you don’t care about the two layers of optional (I.e. not differentiating between `unarchivedArrayOfObjects` returning nil, and an error occurring causing the `try?` to produce nil) and wants the new “flattening” behaviour? In that case, it’s even simpler: you can just keep using your old code as it is.

Comment: I went with:
return try? NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedArrayOfObjects(ofClass: CLLocation.self, from: anonymousCoordinatesArrayData)

since only care if it is nil or a [CLLocation]. 
It worked in my xCode 12.5 but it blew up in the CI that runs xCode 12.5.1 with this error:
error: value of optional type '[CLLocation]??' not unwrapped; did you mean to use 'try!' or chain with '?'?

So now I have :
return try? NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedArrayOfObjects(ofClass: CLLocation.self, from: anonymousCoordinatesArrayData) ?? []
which is not exactly what I intended since it never return nil.